# Display command link in PrimeFaces message

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I am trying to add a command link into PrimeFaces message tag. How can I do that?

MessagesView bean class

```
 @ManagedBean
    public class MessagesView {
        public void info() {
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,
                new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Info","PrimeFaces Rocks."));
        }
    }
```

xhtml

```html
<h:form>
    <p:messages id="messages" showDetail="true" autoUpdate="true"
closable="true" />
    <p:commandButton value="Info" actionListener="#{messagesView.info}" />
</h:form>
```

I want to add this command link to the message.

```html
<p:commandLink id="ajax" actionListener="#{buttonView.buttonAction}">
    <h:outputText value="Submit" />
</p:commandLink>
```

Comment: I'm afraid you can't... Consider the 'name'... it is a message (one way communication). Use a dialog for this (dialog = two way communication) in which you can display the message

Comment: Or a 'panel' that you show or whatever that contains both the messages and the button